# Getting $n number of maximum values

Tags: php

Straight to the question -

If $n = 3,

and input is -

```
Array
(
    [04] => 3
    [07] => 4
    [01] => 5
    [06] => 5
    [05] => 5
    [03] => 6
    [08] => 6
    [02] => 7
    [09] => 8
    [12] => 9
    [10] => 10
    [15] => 10
    [19] => 11
    [20] => 11
    [13] => 12
    [21] => 12
    [16] => 13
    [14] => 14
    [22] => 14
    [23] => 15
    [11] => 15
    [00] => 15
    [17] => 17
    [18] => 17
)
```

Output should be -

```
Array
(   [14] => 14
    [22] => 14
    [23] => 15
    [11] => 15
    [00] => 15
    [17] => 17
    [18] => 17
)
```

Thank you, all, for help.

Comment: Would've been nice if you explained the output a bit. I guess what you want is to have an array that only contains items with the `n` different biggest values (14,15,17 for this input).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
function biggest_n(array $a, $n)
{
  $u = array_unique($a);
  if (count($u) <= $n) return $a;
  rsort($u);
  $val = $u[$n - 1];

  return array_filter($a, function($e) use($val) { return $e >= $val; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arsort($array);
function output($array,$n)
{
  $c=0;
  $newArray=array();
  foreach ($array as $key => $value)
  {
    if ($c == $n)
    {
      $newArray[$key]=$value;
      return $newArray;
    }
    if (!in_array($value, $newArray))
    {
        $c++;
    }
    $newArray[$key]=$value;


  }
}
```

Comment: For the above input, the function outputs Array ( [17] => 17 [18] => 17 [23] => 15 [00] => 15 [11] => 15 [14] => 14 ) The [22] => 14 is missing.

Comment: @KPL:- Now, This is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack into Shakti's function. But, is this reliable?

```
function getMaxValues( $array, $total ) {
    arsort( $array );
    $count = 0;
    $return = array();   
    $total++;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)  {
        if ( !in_array( $value, $return ) )
            $count++;        
        $return[ $key ] = $value;
        if ( $count == $total ) {
            array_pop($return);
            return $return;
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really fast, no loop, only built-in PHP function needed

```
function getMaxValues($array, $number)
{
    $tmp = $array;
    asort($array);

    $values_cnt = array_count_values($array);
    $max_val_cnt = array_slice($values_cnt, count($values_cnt)-$number);
    $max_val_cnt = array_sum($max_val_cnt);

    $ret = array_slice($tmp, count($tmp)-$max_val_cnt, $max_val_cnt, true);

    return $ret;
}
```